# menu link not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a menu where data comes from database.

link **href='slider1.php/" . $row['cat_id'] . "/" . $row['product'] . "'**

My problem is that menu link shows nothing or menu link is not working.

in slider1.php code is as:

```
<?php 
    include('include/config.php');
    $cat = $_GET['cat_id'];
if(isset($cat)){
    if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                                     a.img_id, a.img_name, a.img_type, a.img_size,  b.ad_id, 
                                     b.cus_id, b.ad_name, c.customer, c.mobile,
                                     d.product category,
                                     e.product as subcategory,
                                     f.product as subcat
                                     FROM `image` a 
                                     INNER JOIN `advt` b
                                     ON a.ad_id=b.ad_id
                                     INNER JOIN `customer` c
                                     ON b.cus_id=c.cus_id
                                     INNER JOIN `category` d
                                    ON b.category = d.cat_id 
                                    INNER JOIN `category` e
                                    ON b.subcategory = e.cat_id 
                                    INNER JOIN `category` f
                                    ON b.subcat = f.cat_id AND d.cat_id = '$cat'
                                     GROUP BY b.ad_id
                                     ")){ 


           $stmt->execute(); 
           $stmt->store_result(); 
           $stmt->bind_result($img_id, $img_name, $img_type, $img_size, $ad_id, $cus_id, $ad_name, $customer, $mobile, $category, $subcategory, $subcat);   

           while($stmt->fetch()){ 
           ?>

            <tr class="example">

                <td><?php echo $ad_id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $img_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cus_id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ad_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $customer; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mobile; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subcategory; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subcat; ?></td>
             </tr>

            <?php
           } 
           $stmt->close();
           } 
} 
?>
```

Database extract:

[image]

Menu link;

`<li><a href='/root/as/slider1/" . $row['cat_id'] . "/" . $row['product'] . "'>" . $row['product'] . "</a></li>`

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your example code where you are writing out a link, are you providing the correct sample code?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @gmiley This is my menu link as shown in the 2nd line:  link href='slider1.php/" . $row['cat_id'] . "/" . $row['product'] . "'

Comment: Please include that in your example code so that we can see how you are actually attempting to implement it. Otherwise, we have no idea what you are doing wrong. As your post is now, the example you provided has no value to trying to determine your problem.